# Consuming service with problematic wsdl - Unexpected Element Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl, cxf

I have to consume service with problematic wsdl (cannot change it). At first I had to custom mapping because generated classes were in java.x package. Now I generated vanilla client and tried to use it:

```
    Services handle = new Services(new URL("http://172.16.1.2:8080/axis2/services/x?wsdl"));
    ServicesPortType service = handle
            .getServicesHttpSoap11Endpoint();


    x.y.ws.datamodels.xsd.ObjectFactory obj = new x.y.ws.datamodels.xsd.ObjectFactory();

    IPInterfaceInfo sourceIPInterface = obj.createIPInterfaceInfo();
            service.getInformation(sourceIPInterface);
```

Anyway this code that is doing literally nothing and contains only empty values trows an exception:

```
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://workflowprocessor.ws.y.x}Services# {http://workflowprocessor.ws.y.x}getBandwidthInformation has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://datamodels.ws.y.x/xsd", local:"infoString"). Expected elements are <{http://logging.util.java/xsd}resourceBundleName>,<{http://logging.util.java/xsd}resourceBundle>,<{http://logging.util.java/xsd}parent>,<{http://logging.util.java/xsd}useParentHandlers>,<{http://logging.util.java/xsd}filter>,<{http://logging.util.java/xsd}handlers>,<{http://logging.util.java/xsd}level>,<{http://logging.util.java/xsd}name> 
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:822)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:643)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:157)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:109)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:799)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1635)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1502)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1410)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:650)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:533)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
at $Proxy34.getBandwidthInformation(Unknown Source)
at adva.SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:33)
```

Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

Comment: Have you checked that the response you receive is valid as specified by the wsdl? What is problematic about that wsdl?

Comment: It started with forbidden java namespace. That's why I called it problematic.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker do you mean that error occours while parsing the response, not request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Validation may be disabled by setting an option `set-jaxb-validation-event-handler`, for example:

```
    Services servicehandle = new Services(new URL("http://172.16.2.3:8080/axis2/services/x?wsdl"));
    ServicesPortType port = servicehandle
            .getServicesHttpSoap11Endpoint();



      java.util.Map<String, Object> requestContext =
                               ((javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider)
                port).getRequestContext();
    requestContext.put("set-jaxb-validation-event-handler",  "false");
```

Comment: Thanks, I was running out of options trying to fix the nightmare of WSDL and schemas I received.

Comment: This did not work. Certainly I do not get the error message, but null objects instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
14:35:57,346 WARN  [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] () Interceptor for ****** has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: 2015-10-01T06:44:26+137:00
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:881) [cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:702) [cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:160) [cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
```

Got the above error, Resolved by skipping the validation. Add the below. Thanks Teodozjan.

```
 java.util.Map<String, Object> requestContext =
                               ((javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider)
                port).getRequestContext();
    requestContext.put("set-jaxb-validation-event-handler",  "false");
```

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers